# Facebook "phone updated contact" event

Tags: facebook

What does it mean on Facebook, when there is a note at the top of a friend's profile, saying "phone updated contact" then a number starting 44 then 7 digits?

Answer (score 1):

It means friend has updated his/her phone number on profile in contact details, and number is that given number started with 44.